# How to paint text in an image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, text, paint

I have a image:

It has some time in it.

But I need to convert it to this using python:

this:
[image]
to this
[image]

In short, I need to paint the text in that image black using python. I think maybe opencv is useful for this, But not sure. And I need to do that for any time that will be in that same type of image(like the image before editing, just different digits).
I think we can use canny to detect edges of the digits and the dots and then paint the area between them black. I don't know the perfect way of doing this, but I think it might work. Hoping for a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flood fill will have a hard time since `22` are touched

Comment: Yeah, But isn't there any other solution for this?

Comment: Is that the actual image? The digit are touching, that will create issue, by touching each other they are crearing enclosed area, that is difficult to detect. If the digits arr slightly separated then you can easily use floodfill from `scikit image`

Comment: Other wise you can write custom logic like walking through y axis to fill the gaps

Comment: Also if you know the width of each digit, then it is very easy, you can split the image then apply flood fill to individual section.

Comment: Then should we just let go the 22 ? Because as it can create problems and it isn't needed that much by me so we can just focus on painting the 04:21 digits...

Comment: Even 4:22 can create problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it, I recommend that you play with morphological operations and also look for ways to remove blobs of certain sizes to fix the "22" problem. You can also adjust the tolerance value.

```
import cv2

imgray = cv2.imread('j3iIp.png',0)

point = (0,0)   

src = imgray.copy()

tolerance = 25
connectivity = 4
flags = connectivity
flags |= cv2.FLOODFILL_FIXED_RANGE

cv2.floodFill(src, None, point, (0, 255, 255), (tolerance,) * 3, (tolerance,) * 3, flags)

src = cv2.subtract(255, src) 

cv2.imshow('filled', src)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite("result.jpg",src)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, due to adjascent 22 it is creating problem, so the procedure will be like this

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.segmentation import flood_fill

img = io.imread('number.png', as_gray=True)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

You app ly `flood fill`

```py
ff = flood_fill(img, (0,0), 125)
ff[ff != 125] = 0
ff[ff == 125] = 255

plt.imshow(ff, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Finally, save the image

```py
io.imsave('out.png', ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

The border pixels are turned on to distinguish the characters from background.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('j3iIp.jpg',0)
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img,120,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("result", thresh2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
img1 = cv2.imwrite("thresh4.jpg",thresh2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I first tried using cv2.findContours() but there is no hierarchical difference between the white space inside each character and the white space locked in between 22. The "22 problem" displayed in Epsi95's solution can't be solved using contour hierarchy information.

The problem can be solved using cv2.floodFill() and horizontal edge detection to determine a seed point per object.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Fixed colon locations (assumed to be known constants)
Y1, Y2 = (24, 48)
X1, X2 = (45, 93)

# Plot grayscale image
img = np.uint8(cv2.imread("digits.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) / 255)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].imshow(img, cmap="gray")

# Horizontal edge detection at Y1 to determine the seed points (for flood filling)
kernel = np.array([-1, -1, 1, 1], dtype=np.int8)  # bbww detector
edge_det = np.correlate(img[Y1, :], kernel, mode="same")  # 2 @ bbWw
edge_xloc = np.flatnonzero(edge_det == 2)
seeds_yx = np.array(
    [
        [Y1, edge_xloc[1]],
        [Y1, edge_xloc[edge_xloc < X1][-2]],
        [Y1, X1],
        [Y1, edge_xloc[edge_xloc > X1][1]],
        [Y1, edge_xloc[edge_xloc < X2][-2]],
        [Y1, X2],
        [Y1, edge_xloc[edge_xloc > X2][1]],
        [Y1, edge_xloc[-2]],
        [Y2, X1],
        [Y2, X2],
    ]
)
axs[0].plot(seeds_yx[:, 1], seeds_yx[:, 0], "ro")

# Flood fill at seed points
for y, x in seeds_yx:
    cv2.floodFill(img, mask=None, seedPoint=(x, y), newVal=0)
axs[1].imshow(img, cmap="gray")
fig.show()
```

Code results in this plot [image: filled digits]